# Change multi-site installation from sub-domains to sub-directories

Tags: multisite, installation, subdomains, directory

I've searched everywhere but I don't seem to find a solution for this.

I have a WP installation that is using sub-domains and doesn't have yet any other sites besides the main site. What I want to do, without reinstalling from fresh, is enabling sub-directories.

I tried changing in the wp-config `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );` to `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );` and it allowed to create a site in a sub-directory but when viewing the site I can see only the HTML (no CSS) and I can't access the administration area of the site. I'm guessing there's something else that needs to be done so the paths work.

Any ideas?

Comment: So nobody went trough this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the information [on this page](http://journalxtra.com/2010/07/how-to-force-multi-site-to-use-subdirectories/) <sup>[*mirror*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150307192835/http://journalxtra.com/wordpress/how-to-force-multi-site-to-use-subdirectories)</sup>. I made the change you tried above and the changes to the `.htaccess` file and was able to switch with no problems.